# Short story about a once inhabited planet and some kind of compliance-drug

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this sci-fi short story in a book I found in a waiting room. It was more than 10 years ago and I can't remember if I even got to finish the whole story.

It starts with a spaceship with a small crew and they approach a planet. On the planet is already another crew. The new crew was sent there because the old crew didn't report on time or perhaps they should just replace them, I can not remember.

The old crew tells the new crew, that the planet was once inhabited and that they found underground structures (or perhaps it was just caves). They go there together. The key-element and also the last thing I can remember is, that the old crew tells the new crew in some kind of vestibule, that they had to inhale deeply above some well or something, so that they become understanding (or get aligned with the purpose), before they can go deeper into the structure. They say that the former inhabitants also did this. there may have been mushroom-spores in the air above the well.